# Sharepoint Related issues read only

Tags: sharepoint-online, issue-tracking

Is there a way to make a related issue read-only so a user of the issue tracking system can't edit it? I need this to refer back to other issues if one is the same or something. [image]

Is there a way to hide all the buttons and edit links in this form?
So the white block is totally read-only and not even clickable somewhere?

I hope someone understand it what I am asking.

Comment: By using CSS you can hide elements with e.g. `display: none;` property. However, elements still exist and are in DOM meaning an advanced user could display these buttons through Developer Tools. Are you comfortable with such a solution?

Comment: No, because the little white form that is displayed is the same as the form underneath it. So when I disable it there it is also disabled in the grey big form.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following. You actually _can_ hide elements from the white-background form so that they do not become hidden from the background, although the elements would be same looking and e.g. have the same class & IDs.

Comment: Hmm...  I know how to hide from the form underneath but not how to use css on the upcoming form

Answer (score 0):

By using CSS you can hide elements with e.g. `display: none;` property. However, elements still exist and are in DOM meaning an advanced user could display these buttons through Developer Tools.

With that remark in mind, you can target your dialog's elements (those appearing on the white background form) by including `.ms-formtoolbar` to your CSS locator. This locator should target it to the dialog (though, applies at least when I'm using my SP2013 env).

To e.g. target the buttons on the dialog, try the following:

```
.ms-formtoolbar input {
    display: none;
}
```

Yeah, SP(2013) actually has `button`-type of elements as `input`.

Comment: Wouldn't that also hide the buttons on the main forum?

Comment: @j.Cup with a targeted CSS selector it's possible to apply the style changes, which in this case mean hiding, only to single elements. It might depend a bit on your page's structure/content and on which scope you'd apply this (i.e. does it have to be usable only on one page, etc.). Again you can simulate any style changes with a browser of your choice before applying the changes. Information about how to add new style rules and properties by using e.g. Chrome can be found here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles.